# Тестирование Flask, Peewee, Postgresql

Tags: python, flask

Проблема следующая. Не могу настроить тестовое окружение в Flask-приложение с peewee orm.
Пробовал устанавливать моделям Proxy db

```
import peewee

DATABASE_DATA = {
    'database': 'plan',
    'user': 'plan',
    'password': 'plan'
}

TEST_DATABASE_DATA = {
    'database': 'plan_test',
    'user': 'plan',
    'password': 'plan'
}



proxy_db = peewee.Proxy()


class PlanModel(peewee.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = peewee.Proxy()


def set_database(testing_mode=False):
    if testing_mode:
        db_data = TEST_DATABASE_DATA
    else:
        db_data = DATABASE_DATA
    db = peewee.PostgresqlDatabase(db_data)
    proxy_db.initialize(db)
    return db
```

, но получаю в итоге
 `AttributeError: Cannot use uninitialized Proxy` 
Может есть у вас какой-нибудь cookbook по этой теме. Так же не понимаю как они запускаются во flask, код типа ниже мне вовсе не понятен

```
unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите использовать разные базы данных, то делается это так:
Объявляется базовый класс для моделей:

```
from peewee import *

"""Used for switching between different databases(sqlite,mysql)"""
database_proxy = Proxy()


class BaseModel(Model):
    """Base class of peewee model, used for define model database"""
    class Meta:
        database = database_proxy
```

Добавим наследника:

```
class City(BaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField(db_column='city_id')
    name = CharField(db_column='city_name', max_length=255)
```

Инициировать подключение, создав один из классов:

```
class Sqlite:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Open sqlite connection")
        self._db = SqliteDatabase(":memory:")
        database_proxy.initialize(self._db)


class MySql:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Open MySql connection")
        self._db = MySQLDatabase(
                            config.mysql["db"],
                            host=config.mysql["host"],
                            port=config.mysql["port"],
                            user=config.mysql["user"],
                            passwd=config.mysql["password"])
        database_proxy.initialize(self._db)
```

[Peewee dynamic db define](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#dynamically-defining-a-database)